# Foswiki: Uploading and downloading topics without FTP

Tags: wiki, foswiki

I have a Foswiki wiki on a server. Is it possible to script the following without FTP access (for various reasons I can't use it):

1. Download a topic's wikitext, modify it locally, then upload it again (overwriting the topic)
2. Upload wikitext to a new topic

I've been doing these tasks manually, but I'd like to automate them. I've looked into the Foswiki API and a few plugins, but nothing seems capable of doing this.

Is there a way? (any programming language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have web access, you could drive the bin/view and bin/save scripts remotely from a script.

Take a look at our BuildContrib upload target for an example.  It gets a strikeone key and downloads the original topic to recover any form data.  It then uploads the topic text, creating a new version.   It's written in perl, and uses LWP.

https://github.com/foswiki/distro/blob/master/BuildContrib/lib/Foswiki/Contrib/BuildContrib/Targets/upload.pm

Comment: Pardon the late accept. This is exactly the way we ended up solving it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following **isn't(!)** the right solution (sure exists an nice Foswiki-way approach), but if you know perl, you can do anything with the:

1. Install Firefox
2. install [MozRepl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozrepl/) addon into it
3. Install the [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) perl module

Now, you can script **anything** what you can do directly from the browser, e.g. logging into the Foswiki, click buttons, save topics, etc..etc. Drawback - it isn't an easy way - you need to know many details.

Myself using this technique for testing.